# Can't Deserialize xml using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, datacontractserializer

I can't deserialize this XML to an object, I don't know what is wrong with this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <ProcessOneWayEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/">
        <properties xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CultureLCID>1033</CultureLCID>
        </properties>
    </ProcessOneWayEvent>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is a ready [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RfQMSD) for this, is there any workaround, because I can't modify in the request, so is there any thing wrong with my models?  And is there any solution to deserialize the XML **without using XmlSerializer**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RfQMSD

Comment: You really should include your code **in the question itself**, not just in an external fiddle.  See [ask]: *If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Body` and `SPRemoteEventProperties` need to be in the `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/"` namespace:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/")]
public class Body
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ProcessOneWayEvent")]
    public ProcessOneWayEvent ProcessOneWayEvent;
}

[DataContract(Name = "properties", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/")]
public class SPRemoteEventProperties
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CultureLCID") ]
    public int CultureLCID { get; set; }
}
```

The [`DataContractAttribute.Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace) controls the namespace that the data contract object's **data member elements** are serialized to, as well as the namespace of the root element when the data contract object is the root element.  Since the element `<ProcessOneWayEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/">` declares a new default XML namespace, the element itself, as well as its children, are in this namespace.  Thus, the containing data contract object `Body` must set its data member namespace accordingly.  As for `<properties xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`, the `i:` namespace is not a default namespace, so no elements actually get assigned to this namespace and the `SPRemoteEventProperties` type should not not assign itself to it.

Fixed fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ADG4wa).

Comment: thank you , this really great solution and explanation .

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see why it doesn't work, but one alternative is to use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.

Start by creating the appropriate Envelope classes by copying the XML into a new class (Edit → Paste Special → Paste XML as Classes)

Then deserialize using this as an example:

```cs
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
    Envelope response = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));
}
```

Comment: thank you Berend , but i mentionned that i can't use XmlSerializer due to performance issue

Comment: @Houssem then maybe it would be a good idea to update your question and explicitly mention this requirement :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProcessOneWayEvent", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/remoteapp/")]
        public ProcessOneWayEvent ProcessOneWayEvent { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProcessOneWayEvent
    {
        public Properties properties { get; set; } 
    }
    public class Properties
    {
        public string CultureLCID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            string CultureLCID = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "CultureLCID").FirstOrDefault();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I posted two solutions.  One using the serializer and one using xml linq